# D3 axes render on top of graph

Tags: d3.js

The following code renders the axes on top of the graph and I can't seem to find where to add/subtract pixels to align the two.

I've spent weekend trying to solve this but I feel stuck. In my desperation, I've tried to add and subtract the padding in various places, add margins here and there to move things. It's like the graph and the axes are on two different scales but I can't see where I'm doing that either. This is a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/piacoding/pen/amzoog?editors=0010

thank you,

```
  var w = 780;
  var h = 500;
  var padding = 60;

    var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h )
        .attr('class', 'gdp');

    // define the x scale (horizontal)
    var mindate = new Date(1947, 0, 1),
        maxdate = new Date(2015, 6, 1);

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([mindate, maxdate])
        .range([padding, w - padding]);

    var maxnumber = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1]
    });

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxnumber])
        .range([0, h]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxnumber])
        .range([h - padding, padding]);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - (yScale(d[1]));
        })
        .attr("width",  w / dataset.length)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d[1]);
        })

    // define the y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("left")
        .scale(y);

    // define the y axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("bottom")
        .scale(xScale);

    // draw y axis 
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis);

    // draw x axis 
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Margin Convention](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563) which does exactly what you need. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRovxV?editors=0010 for the updated version:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 60, left: 60};
var width = 780 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr('class', 'gdp');

// define the x scale (horizontal)
var mindate = new Date(1947, 0, 1),
    maxdate = new Date(2015, 6, 1);

// var firstDate = dataset[0];
// var lastDate = dataset[dataset.length - 1][0];

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([mindate, maxdate])
    .range([0, width]);

var maxnumber = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d[1]
});

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxnumber])
    .range([0, height]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxnumber])
    .range([height, 0]);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (width / dataset.length);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return height - (yScale(d[1]));
    })
    .attr("width",  width / dataset.length)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })

// define the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("left")
    .scale(y);

// define the y axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("bottom")
    .scale(xScale);

// draw y axis 
svg.append("g")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);

// draw x axis 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Owen. I took some time to go over the "Margin Convention" and your code, combined they made me see what I didn't understand and where I needed to study.